# How to get a variable in to .load function from select option value?

Tags: html, function, html-select

I need to take a value from select option and pass it to a `load` function.

```
function example_ajax_request2() {
    $('#example-placeholder').html('<p><img src="LINK_TO_IMAGE" width="220" height="19" /></p>');
    $('#example-placeholder').load("LINK_TO_HTML_FILE $('select#example1').val();");
}
```

And this is my selector:

```
<select id="example1" class="selectorM" size="4">
    <option value="#video1" onclick="example_ajax_request2()">1</option>
    <option value="#video2" onclick="example_ajax_request2()">2</option>
</select>
```

Here the video will be loaded:

```
<div id="example-placeholder">
    <p>Placeholding text</p>
</div>
```

Why this is not working?
I need to pass the value from #video1 or #video2 to .load function

I try to get select example1 value with this code

```
$('select#example1').val();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Corect answer!

```
"LINK_TO_HTML_FILE " + $('select#example1').val();
```

insted of

```
"LINK_TO_HTML_FILE" + $('select#example1').val();
```

Thanks anyway! :)

Answer (score 0):

> `""LINK_TO_HTML_FILE $('select#example1').val();"`

This is a literal string containing the actual text `$('select#example1').val();`.
You need to use concatenation:

```
"LINK_TO_HTML_FILE" + $('select#example1').val();
```

Comment: Sorry, it didn't work!     $('#example-placeholder').load("/ktv/templates/kurzemestelevzija/root/youtube/test.html" + $('select#example1').val(););

Comment: If I use   $('#example-placeholder').load('/ktv/templates/kurzemestelevzija/root/youtube/test.html #video2'); Than it works, but I don't need a static value in ,load function!